# how to fix Spring tool suite auto install spring cloud cli error

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

i've download spring tool suite spring-tool-suite-3.9.0.RELEASE-e4.7.0-linux-gtk-x86_64, my environment is ubuntu 16.04 i'm using jdk 8, my question is everytime i start spring tool suite i always get pop up error "auto install spring cloud cli has encountered a problem" and with the detail "CoreException: Failed to execute extension install command". How to fix that did i miss something ? many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use local cloud services from Spring Cloud, you can go to the Boot Dashboard, select the view drop-down menu to customize, and activate the "hide local cloud services".

That prevents the boot dashboard from auto-installing the Spring Cloud CI into the Boot CLI that is configured in the preferences and you should no longer run into the error.

Beyond that, it would be interesting to learn what is causing the error on your machine. So if you would like to provide more details, like stack traces, etc, feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues.

Additional note: We observed that many users are facing this issue and will ship an update release (STS 3.9.1) soon that doesn't install the cloud cli extension by default anymore, but on-demand.